# Oracle STDDEV of elapsed time in seconds

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has start and end times. I'm trying to get the standard deviation of `end - start`.

I ran this:

```
SELECT 
  STDDEV(end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt) AS stddev_elapsed
FROM PROC_STAT ps
WHERE proc_id = 5350;
```

But the result is in days: `0.1360999511817399071975317146959408995275` (~`3.36` hours) - which makes sense, but when I try to cast to seconds it doesn't seem to take:

```
SELECT
  STDDEV(CAST((end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt) AS NUMBER(10,6))) AS stddev_elapsed  
FROM proc_stat ps
WHERE proc_id = 5350;
```

I also tried this, but got an error:

```
SELECT
  STDDEV(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt)) AS stddev_elapsed
FROM proc_stat ps  
WHERE proc_id = 5350;
```

Comment: Why would casting on its own change the value? If you have a value in hours then multiply by 60*60; though the number you have now is in days, so multiply by 24*60*60 (86400). You can then cast or round to a specific precision if you want, of course.

Comment: `ROUND(STDDEV(end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt)*24*60*60) AS stddev_elapsed,`

Comment: If you answer the post I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the number of seconds given a fractional number of days then multiple by 24 to get hours, then 60 to get minutes then 60 to get seconds.

```sql
SELECT STDDEV(end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt) * 24 * 60 * 60
        AS stddev_elapsed
FROM   PROC_STAT ps
WHERE  proc_id = 5350;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT STDDEV((end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt) * 24 * 60 * 60)
        AS stddev_elapsed
FROM   PROC_STAT ps
WHERE  proc_id = 5350;
```

---

`EXTRACT` is for `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` and `INTERVAL` data types, not numbers.

If you want to get the standard deviation in just the seconds component of the difference (ignoring minutes, hours or days) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT STDDEV(
         EXTRACT(
           SECOND FROM
           (end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt) DAY TO SECOND
         )
       ) AS stddev_elapsed
FROM   PROC_STAT ps
WHERE  proc_id = 5350;
```

or use `MOD`ular arithmetic:

```sql
SELECT STDDEV(
         MOD((end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt) * 86400, 60)
       ) AS stddev_elapsed
FROM   PROC_STAT ps
WHERE  proc_id = 5350;
```

*(But that is probably not what you are after, but it shows you how to convert the difference to an `INTERVAL` and use `EXTRACT`.)*

Comment: This is what I used to get the number of seconds: `ROUND(STDDEV(end_proc_dt - start_proc_dt)*24*60*60) AS stddev_elapsed`